# Arduino function similar to Python's "time.sleep()"

Tags: python, time, arduino

I need a similar function to `time.sleep()` of python for using it in arduino.

Comment: Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The function `delay(100)` may help, which 100 corresponds the time in milliseconds.

References:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/

Comment: Thank you very much.